# Mapbox GL JS Api calls control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is there any way to control the API calls of Mapbox GL JS. By this I mean I want API calls to be fired on mouse release. ie If I drag the map from India to USA and drop the cursor at USA, I don't want the tiles in between these two places to load. I want tiles of USA to load. Is there any way to achieve this

By default as I drag the mouse the API calls gets fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one specific way you can do this, and that's using the [transformRequest](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map) option when you create the map:

```js
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  center: [-122.420679, 37.772537],
  zoom: 13,
  style: style_object,
  hash: true,
  transformRequest: (url, resourceType)=> {
    if (!something) {
      return;
    } else {
      return { url } 
    }
  }
});
```

It may be tricky to work out what the "something" is.

Answer (score 0):

The [`dragstart`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:dragstart), [`drag`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:drag), and [`dragend`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:dragend) map events might also be useful here. I'm not entirely sure what your use case here is for preventing tile loads "between" two places, and what that would look like. Is the goal to enhance performance, and would the map just be "blank" in between?

Comment: Yes, the event handlers can be added, what how do we specify to stop the API calls? Yes I don't mind the blank map in between since I am focusing on cost cutting at the moment